# Merge 4 datasets into single datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, dataset

As I wanted to merge 4 datasets into one datagridview. All 4 datasets contains same schema of data.

```
 dgvReport.Rows.Clear();
 DataSet dsResult = objWSX.SelectTopUpReportByCounter(AYear, 
 optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
 DataSet dsResult2 = objWSX.SelectHUGOOnlineTopUpSummary(AYear, 
 optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
 DataSet dsResult3 = objWSX.SelectManjalinkTopUpSummary(AYear, 
 optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
 DataSet dsResult4 = objWSX.SelectReloadCardTopupSummary(AYear, 
 optCurrency.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

And I wanted the output be like this:

For example :

```
          terminal_name        jan     feb    march   april   may
         -----------------------------------------------------
 (dataset1) terminal A          100   200    300      500     700  
 (dataset2)  Counter2           50    120    320      780     600
 (dataset3)   ABC               90    12     45       78       60
 (dataset4)   XYZ               X      X     X         X      X
```

Can you guys help me on this? Thanks!

> > > DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
> > >           DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
> > >           DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
> > >           DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
> >
> > ds2.Merge(ds1);
> >         ds3.Merge(ds2);
> >         ds4.Merge(ds3);

Comment: If schema is same for all  then Merge All datasets then give that final dataset as source to gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();

ds2.Merge(ds1);
Gridview.DataSource = ds2;
```

Comment: this only applicable for two datasets right? @Mohammad

Comment: No.There is no limit .Its just an example to show how you can do it.
In your case,create a new dataset and merge all 4 datasets one by one.

Comment: is it the correct way as i do it in my questions? @Mohammad

Comment: Yes it is .Did you got your desired result?

Comment: i have to make some testing data first  @mohammad

Comment: If it helps you then do mark it as an answer.Thankyou